# How do I make a REVERSE CALENDAR?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I have a request from my regional manager to create an availability calendar that shows who is available and when. The pure opposite of a event calendar. I have approximately 50 people who are all attached to multiple projects with start and stop dates for each project. I can very easily put all the projects on a calendar. I can also easily put all the people on a calendar with start stop dates. How do I display the days they are not working? I honestly do not know where to start this one, I have mocked up event lists, personnel lists with calendar views, but none seam to show what I need. The only thing I can think of that may work is to have a series of nested lists. Main List: All Personnel SubLists: Each person has a calendar of events Overlay each list on one large calendar But this still shows when they are working, not when they are off. Green- Days they are working (Easy to show, I don’t want to see this by default) Red – Days they are off, I need only the red days to display for the whole crew. Either in a list by day or a calendar.

Comment: Have you looked into using CSS to 'hide' all events, and then highlight days where no events are listed?

Comment: I dont foresee that working, there will be events every day of the year due to the amount of projects going on. I need it to be a list of when employees are not working.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I had to do a similar for a client: they didn't want to show who is not working per se, but rather who was on-site, off-site, or not working. We setup a separate list that tracked these values. A simple solution might be this:

1. Create a new Calendar List.
2. For each employee, create a daily recurring event called "Available".
3. Whenever an item is created in your CURRENT Calendar, delete the recurring event for that employee on the specified date.